# "Nested" queries in SQL / SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy (being relatively new both to it and SQL) and I want to get a list of all comments posted to a set of things, but I'm only interested in comments that have been posted since a certain date, and the date is different for each thing:

To clarify, here's what I'm doing now: I begin with a dictionary that maps the ID code of each thing I'm interested in to the date I'm interested in for that thing. I do a quick list comprehension to get a list of just the codes (`thingCodes`) and then do this query:

```
things = meta.Session.query(Thing)\
    .filter(Thing.objType.in_(['fooType', 'barType']))\
    .filter(Thing.data.any(and_(Data.key == 'thingCode',Data.value.in_(thingCodes))))\
    .all()
```

which returns a list of the thing objects (I do need those in addition to the comments). I then iterate through this list, and for each thing do a separate query:

```
comms = meta.Session.query( Thing )
    .filter_by(objType = 'comment').filter(Thing.data.any(wc('thingCode', code))) \
    .filter(Thing.date >= date) \
    .order_by('-date').all()
```

This works, but it seems horribly inefficient to be to be doing all these queries separately. So, I have 2 questions:

a) Rather than running the second query n times for an n-length list of things, is there a way I could do it in a single query while still returning a separate set of results for each ID (presumably in the form of a dictionary of ID's to lists)? I suppose I could do a `value_in(listOfIds)` to get a single list of all the comments I want and then iterate through that and build the dictionary manually, but I have a feeling there's a way to use `JOIN`s for this.

b) Am I over-optimizing here? Would I be better off with the second approach I just mentioned? And is it even that important that I roll them all into a single transactions? The bulk of my experience is with Neo4j, which is pretty good at transparently nesting many small transactions into  larger ones - does SQL/SQLAlchemy have similar functionality, or is it definitely in my interest to minimize the number of queries?